# Replace each whitespace in a string with "%20"

Tags: c#, strings, .net

My implementation:

```
string ReplaceAllSpaces(string input)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(input))
    {
        while(reader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            char c = (char)reader.Peek();
            if(char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                while(char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) 
                { 
                    reader.Read(); 
                    c = (char)reader.Peek();
                } 
                builder.Append("%20");
            }
            else builder.Append((char)reader.Read()); 
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Input:

```
"My      Name Is  John"
```

Output:

```
"My%20Name%20Is%20John"
```

How could this be improved?  Only ASCII characters are permitted.

Comment: Is there something you're trying to accomplish that `input.Replace(" ", "%20");` won't?

Comment: This replaces several consecutive spaces with a single `%20`. Is this the desired behaviour? Usually each space would be replaced by a single `%20`.

Comment: @mjolka Yes. I'll add some more information to the question.

Comment: @mjolka I've also changed the title. I hope that now it makes more sense.

Comment: Is there a problem with UrlEncode() ? Gets all non-roman characters, not just spaces.

Comment: Are you certain that it's *only* spaces you need to escape as percent-encoded characters? There are other characters besides spaces which need to be precent-encoded when used in a URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters (If you need to escape these characters too, it's probably a good idea to use a library.)

Comment: @Ajedi32 No. You only have to replace WhiteSpace strings with %20.

Comment: Just to check, can your input ever contain `%` signs (or, specifically, the string `%20`)? Does the input need to be unambiguously reconstructible from the output? (If answers to both questions are "yes", you may have a problem.)

Comment: @llmariKaronen what's the problem?

Comment: Obviously the problem is: if your input can contain %20, then it could be: "My%20Name%20Is%20John". The output results exactly the same of your example, so you can not unambiguously reconstruct the input from the output

Answer (score 40):

This one really fits well for a regular expression:

```
public static string ReplaceAllSpaces(string str) {
  return Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+","%20");
}
```

The expression `\s+` consists of the pattern `\s` that matches a whitespace character (which is more that just spaces, as noted by @tinstaafl), and the quantifier `+` which means "at least once".

The pattern matches "one or more whitespace characters", so it will match each group of whitespace characters (for example the six spaces between `My` and `Name` in the example) and replace it with `%20`.

Comment: This is what Regexes were made for.

Comment: The only correct answer in my opinion. No need to write lines of code for something which can be done in such a simple way. =)

Comment: would you please explain for OP how this does exactly the same as his code but is much better? I always have to look up Regex if I need to use it, so does your code replace 5 spaces with one `%20` or does it replace them with `%20%20%20%20%20`

Comment: @Malachi: this is a very simple regex. It is composed of a pattern and a quantifier. the pattern is `\s`, or `whitespaces` (btw, this englobes much more that just spaces, as noted by @tinstaafl), and the quantifier is `+`, which is `at least once`.

Comment: @njzk2 thank you for the explanation, it would be nice to have that edited into the answer so that this is more of an on-topic answer. I hope that Guffa explains his answer a little better, then I wouldn't feel so bad up voting it.

Comment: @njzk2: Thanks for the suggested edit. I used most of it (just wanted to put it in my own words), and added an example from the data in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Since a string is basically a character array, I would do away with the stringreader and simply loop through the string itself:

```
    static string ReplaceAllSpaces(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        bool continuousSpace = false;
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (!continuousSpace && char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                builder.Append("%20");
                continuousSpace = true;
            }
            else if(!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                builder.Append(c);
                continuousSpace = false;
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

A side note:  [Whitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Char.IsWhiteSpace%29;k%28IsWhiteSpace%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) includes a lot of other characters in the unicode set as well as the space.

> White space characters are the following Unicode characters:
>
> Members of the SpaceSeparator category, which includes the characters
>
> SPACE (U+0020), OGHAM SPACE MARK (U+1680), MONGOLIAN VOWEL
>   SEPARATOR (U+180E), EN QUAD (U+2000), EM QUAD (U+2001), EN SPACE
>   (U+2002), EM SPACE (U+2003), THREE-PER-EM SPACE (U+2004), FOUR-PER-EM
>   SPACE (U+2005), SIX-PER-EM SPACE (U+2006), FIGURE SPACE (U+2007),
>   PUNCTUATION SPACE (U+2008), THIN SPACE (U+2009), HAIR SPACE (U+200A),
>   NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F), MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F),
>   and IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE (U+3000).
>
> Members of the LineSeparator category, which consists solely of the LINE SEPARATOR character (U+2028).
>
> Members of the ParagraphSeparator category, which consists solely of the PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR character (U+2029).
>
> The characters CHARACTER TABULATION (U+0009), LINE FEED (U+000A), LINE TABULATION (U+000B), FORM FEED (U+000C), CARRIAGE RETURN
>   (U+000D), NEXT LINE (U+0085), and NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0).

Comment: Let's ignore Unicode for now.

Comment: The whitespace category will still include those character codes that are considered ASCII(9,10,11,12,13,32, etc.)